# How to convert require to import?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

How do you convert the following code to ES6:

```js
const uu = require('url-unshort')();

try {
  const url = await uu.expand('https://on.soundcloud.com/EC23');

  if (url)
     console.log(`Original url is: ${url}`);
  else 
     console.log('This url can\'t be expanded');

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

This snippet is from https://github.com/nodeca/url-unshort, a node package that unshorts links. However, the import/require part made me stumble.

```js
const uu = require('url-unshort')();
```

I have seen `require('')` and `import { } from pkg` alone and have used them. But it's my first time to see a `require('')` and then besides it another `()`.

To add to my confusion, I think `url-unshort` has no modules inside of the package that I can extract using `import { } from 'url-unshort'`. I did try the following:

```js
import * as uu from 'url-unshort';
```

But I think I'm missing a step because it doesn't work still.

Comment: ` require('url-unshort')` returns one function (`Unshort`) that can be and is immediately executed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the default export of `require('url-unshort')` is a function and you should call it.

So the solution would be:

```js
import Unshort from 'url-unshort';
const uu = Unshort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `import` statement instead of `const uu = require('url-unshort')();` to import the required module.

```
import urlUnshort from 'url-unshort';
const uu = urlUnshort();

(async () => {
  try {
    const url = await uu.expand('https://on.soundcloud.com/EC23');

    if (url) {
      console.log(`Original url is: ${url}`);
    } else {
      console.log("This url can't be expanded");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```